# Format multiline command output in bash using printf

Tags: linux, bash, formatting, printf, multiline

My Bash script uses `printf` to print output of some other commands with formatting applied, in the following manner (note the two leading spaces):

```
printf "  %-16s %s\n" "foo:" "$(bar)"
```

The two leading spaces are there, because the first line in the file is a comment, and I like to keep things nicely aligned:

```
# foo
  foo:            bar
  foo:            bar
  ...
```

This works perfectly fine for commands with one-line output. However, when the output is multiline, the output looses the formatting of the subsequent lines.

For example:

```
printf "  %-16s %s\n" "Contents:" "$(ls -a)"
```

Results in something like this:

```
  Contents:       .
..
foo
bar
```

Instead, what I am trying to achieve is multiline output, with each line formatted (in columns, if you like), which would look like this (note the lack of "header" in the subsequent lines):

```
  Contents:       .
                  ..
                  foo
                  bar
```

My understanding so far is that `printf` with two arguments (the first one being a string, and the other one the result of the given command) treats the second argument as a single string, which can include newline characters within. Therefore, the output is actually correctly formatted, according to what I asked `printf` to do, but it is not what I am looking for.

I am aware about some of the pitfalls related to parsing the output of commands like `ls`, which exhausts my current possibilities of solving this problem. Also, it is possible that `printf` is not the best facility to do this.

I am considering substituting multiline string into comma-separated list, if no solution to this problem is possible, but this would be a last resort.

What would be the best method to achieve the formatting I need?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf "  %-16s %s\n" "foo:" "$(bar | sed '2,$s/^/                   /g')"
```

Comment: It appears to be working. How about an explanation? As far as I understand, you are replacing each occurrence of newline with fixed amount of spaces?

Comment: yes, `2,$s` means from line 2 to end of file, replace `^`(start of line) to spaces.

Comment: Thank you, it will do just fine for now. I didn't think about substitution for some reason. Just out of curiosity, is there any more flexible solution (i.e. one that would determine the padding for both `printf` and `sed`)?

Comment: Since there are no more comments on the subject, I will accept your answer. Anyhow, if anyone has an alternate solution, please contribute.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it difficult to apply the same print instructions to a range of commands. Also output from ls can be tedious to examine because it selects an output format depending upon environment variables.

I found the following worked well for ls on my Mac:

```
x=$(ls -a); 
x=${x//$'\n'/$'\n'                    }; 
printf "   %-16s %s" "Contents:" "$x" $'\n'
```